# Pandoc HTML to DOCX: how to correctly specify the alternative text of an image

Tags: html, docx, pandoc, alt

When converting an HTML file to a DOCX file with Pandoc, I would have expected that the `alt` attribute of an image would be converted to the image caption (with "Image Caption" style) in a DOCX file. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

It only seems to work for me with Markdown's syntax: with `![alt text](xxx.jpg)`, the alt text is converted to an "Image Caption" styled element in Word.

But I don't get it to work with HTML, even a `<figure>`'s `<figcaption>` is only converted to a standard paragraph, not to an "Image Caption" style in Word.

How should it be done in HTML?

Comment: Are you setting [fig_caption: true](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#figure-options)?

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a reference like http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/, but it's not really pandoc, but an R enhanced variant, right? Is there something similar especially for pandoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of Pandoc (e.g. 2.9.x) the `alt` attribute is used as the alternative text, as expected.

So `![alt text](xxx.jpg)` does work perfectly now. Thanks, Pandoc team!

Answer (score 2):

The following HTML will be [converted to a figure](http://pandoc.org/try/?text=%3Cp%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%22xxx.jpg%22+alt%3D%22alt+text%22+title%3D%22fig%3A%22%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&from=html&to=html):

```
<p><img src="xxx.jpg" alt="alt text" title="fig:"></p>
```

There are two tricks to this:

1. The `img` must be alone in a paragraph
2. the `title` attribute must start with `fig:`